# Get search term with regex pattern in an url

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics

In my website, I have these search url types :

*https://www.example.org/folder/subfolfer/(search_text)/theterme%20i%20want/(search_on)/all/(limit)/48/(sort)/order*

or

*https://www.example.com/Folder/subfolder/mysearchdir/(only_lowercase)/false/(search_text)/theterme i want*

In my analytics backoffice, I have set this regex :

```
\((search_text)\)\/(.*)(?=\(search)
```

And I have tried this one :

```
\((search_text)\)\/(\w*)
```

But it takes only the first word and it doesn't match if the word contains special french characters like ô or ë.

Is it possible to have a regex would take everything between "/(search_text)/" until the next slash?

Comment: Yep, just use something like `[^\/]*` instead of `.*` to capture everything except a slash

Comment: So, `\(search_text\)\/([^\/]+)`?

Comment: you can use `URLSearchParams.get` [browser documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#Example), [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams)

Comment: Thanks all! @Wictor's solution seems to work but if a have spaces, it only takes the first word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the grouping parentheses from the part of pattern you are not using later and use `[^\/]+` to match any char but `/`, one or more times, instead of `\w*`:

```
/\(search_text\)\/([^\/]+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KQYjJ6/1)

**Details**

- `\(search_text\)\/`  - a literal `(search_text)/` text
- `([^\/]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `/`.

Comment: Thanks, I will change just the end to add other params liste /(search_on), but this solution works great. 


Thanks